# How to implement live tracking?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like implement a live tracking in Android using Google maps. I want to show the user's movement as they move from one location to another by changing the position of the marker on the map.

Answer (score 1):

> Because the user location changes, you must account for movement by
>   re-estimating user location every so often.

read the full story here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to make `LocationRequest` after a fix interval and listen to location change using `LocationListener`. You can refer this good example :-

http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-tracker-with-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

To implement LiveTracking in a Android or IOS Application, the following tedious process includes,
 The real time technology to update your location and a dedicated server that should handle the loads of data inorder to receive the location  values of a driver for a certain interval. The Algorithm you creates has to provide less battery consumption while the application runs in the background. All this has to be accompanied with security to ensure the reliability of application.

And here's a easy way by you can integrate LiveTracking in seconds:
    A Tailored Solution is available to you, Teliver is a Location Tracking SDK avilable for both Android and IOS Application. The SDK has to be integrated in two application.

1. One application as a CONSUMER.
2. Another application as a OPERATOR.

Assuming a On-Demand delivery service as a use-case for you to implement LiveTracking. Once the Delivery-agent is out to delivery then the customer can track the location of delivery agent in maps, The marker will update based on every location update of the driver in Maps.

[image]