# How to create an Android GPS Live tracking application?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I want to create an app which can track the location of a person on Map while he is moving.I want a live tracking system.I searched in google and got few references.I got this [How to implement live tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646480/how-to-implement-live-tracking) as reference from stackoverflow,but this is not an updated reference.Actually I want something like currently uber has implemented recently https://newsroom.uber.com/trip-tracker/ , http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3597287/Uber-lets-track-family-friends-App-launches-tool-allows-loved-one-s-journey-real-time.html. Any kind of help will be useful for me.Please give me a start.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No. You should make the start. And know what you want. Then if you have problems you call SO. And please do not thank in advance. Bad habbit.

Comment: Okay.I have started with the help of links I attached above.The problem is the classes used there are of old versions.If you know please share few references,so that I can move forward referring those

Answer (score 0):

You can create two Applications, that is:

- One acts as a CONSUMER;
- Another one as an OPERATOR.

The location of an OPERATOR can be updated in a certain interval and the device that acts as a CONSUMER will receive the location updates and plot the location in maps.

That is the location of a transmitter who is ready to transmit, and whose location will be tracked.

You can achieve it integrating a SDK named TELIVER [Live Tracking made easier](https://teliver.io) that allows to create a GPS tracking Android application easily.